# PHP based scrum tool

Tags: open-source, php

I am currently working with my team using manual scrum board and charts. I need a software that simplifies this manual work and saves all actions in a database.

And because we work as a PHP programming team, we have the infrastructure of our development lab built with wamp and netbeans on top of Ubuntu.

So I saw many software that implements scrum but most of them aren't written in PHP. The best one I saw is iceScrum (java based).

I googled a lot and I found some alternatives to iceScrum written in PHP but they are minimal in features. Most of them doesn't have burn down charts or product backlog:

1. [scrumblr](http://scrumblr.ca/) (it only gives a scrum board)
2. [kanboard](http://kanboard.net) (it has scrum board, projects, users, activity and analytics; But there is no burn down charts)

Any ideas ? I will contribute to the project

Note: I need it to be open source of course and having at least the following: scrum board, project, users and burn down charts)

Note: I saw this closed SO question [Which open-source Scrum project management tool do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113241/which-open-source-scrum-project-management-tool-do-you-use) but can't find a good PHP one.

Comment: Your question is a bit 'skinny'. Can you [edit] it and fill in requirements? You can't expect us to do the work of going to those 3 sites and do all the comparisons for you. Please read: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software

Comment: @JanDoggen As I said Most of them doesn't have burn down charts or product backlog. That's what I want specifically in addition to the scrum board

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Most issue trackers nowadays provide scrumb features, don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still interested in this, you may go and search for zentao in google.
scrum board, project, users and burn down charts are all included in zentao.
It's written by PHP over 90%, you could go to their github page by, https://github.com/easysoft/zentaopms
Or their website, [www.zentao.pm](http://www.zentao.pm)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Kados : http://www.kados.info

It is a PHP tool for managing SCRUM backlogs. My team uses it since 2013. It's pretty cool since it displays postits in a lot of boards and it's quite simple to start with